# how to highlight a search query in my results inside template

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2, whoosh

Ok, so I have this simple search page implemented with `Flask-WhooshAlchemy`

```
@views.route('/search', methods=['GET'])
def search():
    query = request.args['query']
    results = []

    def _model_search(m):
        return m.query.whoosh_search(query).all()

    if query:
        for model in [Student, StudentHomework, Winner]:
            results += _model_search(model)

    return render_template(
        'search.html',
        query=query,
        results=results,
    )
```

Then, in my search template, I am outputing the found `results`. How can I highlight the matched query?

For example on my `Student` table I am searching in `name` and `forname` columns. And in my template I do something like:

```
{% for student in results %}
  {% student.name %}
  {% student.forname %}
{% endfor %}
```

How can I highlight where the query string has a match?

Comment: I think I know the answer to this, but you'll have to elaborate a little bit more. Do you want to highlight the __field__ with a match? (for example, if the student name matches, highlight the student name). What exactly do you want to highlight?

Comment: I want to highlight only the occurences of the search `query`. like you would do in a browser CTRL + F and find a word. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

It's too late to answer but I hope it will help someone in the future.
Even when I saw this question I was having the same issue when I figure out a solution I thought it's better to share.

although you are looking to highlight two columns. But I can able to highlight only one column.

```
{% for student in results %}
  {% if query in student.name %}
      {{ student.name.replace(query, '<span style="background-color: yellow;">{}</span>'.format(query)) }}
  {% endif %}
  {% else %}
      {{ student.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

if these is a query in student.name's column it will highlight as <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

Note: query is the search input content

Comment: Are you sure that solution works? I do not have huge experience with flask, but I think it won't let you just put HTML tags like that, it wil HTMLEncode them replacing `<>` with `&lt;&gt;`

Comment: Obviously your answer doesn't work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31489609/render-html-tags-from-variable-without-escaping
My friend learning programming flask spent way too much time wondering what's wrong with that thing because of your low quality answer.